# Tkinter programming

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a basic tk window and kept a button to delete all widgets but an imprint of the widgets is left over.

How can I remove that blank part?
problem still persists

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

  def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)                 
    self.master = master
    self.init_window()
  def init_window(self):   
    self.master.title("SAMPLE")
    self.pack(expand=1)
    loginb = Button(self, text="Log in",command=self.LogIn, height=2, width=20)
    loginb.grid(row=1)

  def Quit(self):
        exit()
  def LogIn(self):
        for widget in Frame.winfo_children(self):
              widget.destroy()
        self.grid_forget()
        self.grid()
        e1
        self.L = {}
        Label1 = Label(text="Enter your code:").grid(row=1,column=0)
        E1 = Entry(textvariable=e1).grid(row=1,column=1)
        def  F1():
              self.L["Code"] = e1.get()
              return
        B1 = Button(text="Ok", command=F1).grid(row=1,column=2)
root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x700")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove frame itself as well. It's the frame that is leftover.

```
def LogIn(self):
    for widget in Frame.winfo_children(self):
        widget.destroy()
    self.pack_forget()
```

Looking at your Menu though, you probably will need those buttons back again so instead of re-creating them each time after using `widget.destroy()`, you should use `widget.grid_forget()` and use `widget.grid()` when they are needed again.

**EDIT**: Added a dummy menu button to show how to add other widgets

```
class Window(Frame):
  def __init__(self, master=None):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    file.add_command(label="dummybutton", command=self.add_widget)

  def LogIn(self):
        for widget in Frame.winfo_children(self):
              widget.destroy()
        self.pack_forget()

  def add_widget(self):
      #here you are packing again
      #since pack doesn't remember config options, 
      #you need to specify those here as well like expand etc.
      self.pack(expand=1) 
      #adding dummy widget to show it adds without a problem
      Button(self, text="dummy widget").pack()
```

Comment: pack frame again first with self.pack(). Then do your widget additions.

Comment: @CompStudent edited answer to add an example on how to do it.

Comment: but my code(which also contains an Entry widget) gives an error: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

Comment: @CompStudent Then change those pack ones to grid as well. In _same container_, you should stick to one geometry manager. If you used grid on one, you should use grid on all.

Comment: this is what ive done:                                                                                                    for widget in Frame.winfo_children(self):
         widget.destroy()
self.pack_forget()
self.(expand=1)
loginb = Button(self, text="Log in",command=self.LogIn, height=2, width=20).grid(row=1)                                                                                E1 = Entry().grid(row=1,column=1)                                                                                 but it seems to show error only for the entry widget

Comment: use grid on self as well. at the beginning in your init method, change it as self.grid( ... ) and in your LogIn method, change it to self.grid_forget(). When you are gonna use self again, use self.grid()